# wordwrap of non english (hindi) charaters clipping the right edge in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, word-wrap, non-english

**Created a Listview with Non English (Hindi) characters, resulting in text being clipped to the right where its suppose to be wrapped. Image seen below.**

However same code setup is working for English text.

[image: right margin and padding set to 0]

Also tried adding padding and margin to the listview item,result below.

Note : I was using android 4.1.2 (16).

[image: right margin and padding set to 20dp]

code of the list view listview :

```
       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 

        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>
```

and the textview used in the list item of the custom adapter is :

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/main_text"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:text="@string/verse"
     android:textColor="#000000"

     android:paddingTop="5dp"

     android:gravity="top|left"
     android:paddingRight="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:singleLine="false"


     android:textSize="18dp" />
```